# What type does a component have in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme, jestjs

I'm new to using typescript.  I am passing a component to another component for testing because it has some silly dependencies. The receiving component will have the parameter component listed in its props. Since I'm using typescript, I'll have to give it a type. What type do I need to give it?

I need to avoid including the file because I want to mock it essentially. (Maybe there is a better way to do this, I was planning on replacing it with a function in the tests.)

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
// Parent Component
import { Thing } from '../thing'

export default class SomeParent extends React.Component<Props, {}> {


  public render() {
      return (
        <Prem
          Thing={Thing}
        />
      )
  }  
}


// Prem file
export interface Props {
  Thing: What goes here?
}

export default class Prem extends React.Component<Props, {}>{

  // Do stuffs  
  public render() {
    return (
      <Thing>
        <div> herp derp </div>
      </Thing>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `React.Component` is unsuitable?

Comment: What about [`React.ComponentClass<P>`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L237)?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `React.ComponentClass<{}>` or the `React.SFC<{}>` (the later for stateless components) classes.

```
var thing : React.ComponentClass<{}> = ThingComponent
var sfThing : React.SFC<{}> = props => <div></div>  {/*Your component's markup*/}
```

And to create an instance, use:

```
React.createElement(thing, {props}, [children])
```

where `{props}` is key-value paired object representing prop keys and values.